# Python: Superclass that picks an appropriate subclass for new instances

Tags: python, class, factory, superclass

This question is strictly about elegant programming.

I am implementing dozenal (base-12) numbers (they go 0, 1, 2, . . . , 8, 9, *, #, 10) in Python 3.

I intend for them to act very similarly to regular ints and floats, as such:

```
>>> a = Dozenal(1000)

>>> a
DozenalInt('6#4')

>>> b = Dozenal(80.9)

>>> b
DozenalFloat('68.X9724972497249725')

>>> isinstance(a, Dozenal) and isinstance(b, Dozenal)
True

>>> isinstance(a, DozenalInt)
True

>>> isinstance(a, DozenalFloat)
False

>>> type(a)
DozenalInt
```

So far, since new class instances can’t create other classes, I gather that `Dozenal()` must be a factory function, that returns either `DozenalInt` or `DozenalFloat` object depending on argument.

But how do I also make `Dozenal` a superclass for `DozenalInt` or `DozenalFloat`, while being of the same name as the factory function?

Or am I taking a wrong road here?

Identical names are important for me for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Just make `Dozenal.__new__` return the appropriate subclass instance.

Comment: This sounds more like an output formatting issue than something that should affect the internal representation. (Also, `a` and `b` are more usual choices than `*` and `#`.)

Comment: Oh. And what will happen to all those empty instances of Dozenal? Or are they trashed?

Comment: It won't make empty `Dozenal` instances to clean up in the first place.

Comment: Watch out for double-initialization, though. If you use `__new__`, you should usually place all initialization of these objects in `__new__` methods and not use `__init__`.

Comment: Looks like `__new__` is the way to go, haven’t thought about it. Will research the double initialization. Thanks a bunch to all.